# Angular templating: bind i18n values from service more convenient

Tags: angular, service, angular2-template, templating

I have lots of internationalized stuff in my app. Of course I have to bind the translated values somehow. Basic example:

```
<h3>{{ this.localizationService.localized['welcomeHeaderExpression'] }}</h3>

<p>{{ this.localizationService.localized['introText'] }}</p>
```

What's best practice for doing such things more easy? Just by setting a property in the component like `private i18n: any = this.localizationService.localized`?
The goal is to use it more convenient like this:

```
<h3>{{ i18n['welcomeHeaderExpression'] }}</h3>

<p>{{ i18n['introText'] }}</p>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `this` in template expressions at all. If you have LocalizationService named as localizationService in component class, you use it as `localizationService.localized`. If you have it named as i18n, you use it as `i18n`. It's just a property of component class instance. So yes, it is `private i18n: any = this.localizationService.localized`.

Comment: Makes sense - the problem though: the contents are async, which means the values won't be available when constructing the component. Setting the values in each component manually isn't very convenient too. What would you recommend?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Is it localizationService.localized object that isn't available? If this is an issue, please, update the question to reflect the whole problem. This can be solved with a pipe or an observable or whatever. I would suggest to check existing solutions (e.g. ng2-translate) instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks alot!